# Expression for bison & flex

Tags: boolean, expression, bison, yacc

I create a Yacc parsing Boolean expression:

```
boolean { $$ = $1; }

| expr '*' expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }

| expr '+' expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }

| '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2;}
;
```

But it is not enough for the expression like `!(T+F)*F+!T`. How to modify it in a simple way?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add one line `'!' expr {$$=!($2);}`